# mathieu group M23?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

what is Mathieu group M23?is there an paper published about mathieu group M23?

Comment: The book "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer is a good reference about Mathieu Groups. BTW, a simple Wikipedia search gives you a lot of information about them, including a quite long bibliography...

Comment: Rotman's "Introduction to the Theory of Groups" likewise has a treatment of Mathieu groups (Chapter 9).

Comment: yeah obviously there would be a published paper On M23...unfortunately I was not able to view it....is there any reference to ret

Comment: thanks for your response...i have tried my level best to retrieve the related paper from the **here** link mentioned by Zev Chonoles.

Comment: thanks for your guidence..i have retrieved the paper...

Comment: @sumaira: please do not use answers to comment. The reason you could not comment on your own question (which you ordinarily should be able to) is that you have not registered your account, so please do so soon.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/group/M23/) is what Mathieu group $M_{23}$ is. And [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=4877496) is a paper on it (though really, did you think that there might not ever have been a single paper published about it?)

Comment: @Grigory: [This](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700010247) was the intended link, but I see Zev's edited it now...

Comment: @J.M. I'll just use your link (I suspect I was able to see the paper using the original link as I'm on a university network).